# Integers being converted from 64bit to 32bit with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am storing 64bit Facebook ids in our mysql database. When I view the database table the values are 32bit. I am using Laravel, with the PDO connection. The values, if dumped out, are correct in the bindings. Once executed they are different in the DB. I have tried changing database from MariaDB to MySQL to see if it was the database causing it. Everything points to it being PDO.

This does not happen on my local development machine which is using the exact same version of `PHP 7.0.15`. I get no errors on either development or local.

MySQL and PHP are 64bit versions. I have not been able to find anything that helps me resolve the issue.

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63916) from 2013 that clearly illustrates my issue but seems to have been resolved.

In Laravel's Connection class the `bindValues` method is checking the data type like so.

```
public function bindValues($statement, $bindings)
{
    foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
        dump($value); // Value is correct at this point.
        $statement->bindValue(
            is_string($key) ? $key : $key + 1, $value,
            is_int($value) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR
        );
    }
}
```

I have also tried setting the third param to just be `PDO::PARAM_STR` but that didn't change the behavior.

The server is `CentOS Linux 7.3.1611`, MySQL is `5.7.17`, PHP `7.0.15`

PDO and MySql Extensions

```
php70w-pdo.x86_64                   7.0.15-1.w7 @webtatic
php70w-mysql.x86_64                 7.0.15-1.w7 @webtatic
```

The table is `InnoDB` with `UTF-8 Unicode` encoding and the collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`

The sql connection is:

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => true,
'modes' => ['STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'],
'engine' => null,
```

What things can I try to resolve my issue?

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: The column is a varchar(100). I have tried BIGINT and I got an out of range error.

Comment: You'll have to show how you get and echo it as it should work fine as they are strings unless you cast them, calculate them etc...

Comment: in your PDO, cast values that you are passing to it into strings using `':field'=>strval($value)` and see if that works

Comment: So its an `int` in PHP and you attempt to store as an `int` but its a varchar?

Comment: I am storing it as and varchar because the BIGINT made it go out of range. @Dimi casting it to a string didn't change anything. Which is making me think it might be mysql. I also got the compiled query and ran it on the server and the values didn't convert.

Comment: Was BIGINT signed?

Comment: ...or unsigned? There's a big difference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: The BIGINT was unsigned. Which means that's why the out of range happened with the negative 32bit

Comment: Try var_dump'ing at the time of insertion to see what's being passed in there exactly and compared from what the original input is. You should also update your question in regards to what type of server it's on, the OS (Linux, Windows) etc. with as much technical information as possible (and if it's InnoDB or other). I can't wrap my head around this one, it's baffling. Make sure there are no stray trailing spaces or (hidden) unicodes. This could also be an encoding issue. Passing a UTF-8 in the connection is worth trying.

Comment: @Dimi forcing the value to a string makes it work. So this is definitely a PDO issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Our server was using the regular `php70-mysql` drivers and not the native drivers `php70-mysqlnd`. Once we updated that the integers were preserved.